# How to get stdout and stderr unbuffered or at least in order from child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's a simple node program: (note: this is just an example. substitute any program that outputs to both stdout and stderr and for which if the lines are out of order they won't be that useful, examples llvm, gcc, clang, less, grep, etc...)

```
const log = msg => console.log(`log: ${msg}`);
const error = msg => console.error(`error: ${msg}`);

log('line1');
error('line2');
log('line3');
error('line4');
```

If I run it I get this output:

```
log: line1
error: line2
log: line3
error: line4
```

Now I want the same output from `child_process.execFile`. The problem is the lines are buffered so they don't arrive to me in the same order:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const lines = [];
const ch = child_process.execFile(process.argv[0], ['main.js'], () => {
  console.log(lines.join(''));
});
ch.stdout.on('data', (data) => { lines.push(data); });
ch.stderr.on('data', (data) => { lines.push(data); });
```

produces:

```
log: line1
error: line2
error: line4
log: line3
```

As another example here's a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo line 1
echo line 2 >&2
echo line 3
echo line 4 >&2
```

and running it in a terminal the output is:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

but running it via `child_process`:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const lines = [];
const ch = child_process.execFile('sh', ['test.sh'], () => {
  console.log(lines.join(''));
});
ch.stdout.on('data', (data) => { lines.push(data); });
ch.stderr.on('data', (data) => { lines.push(data); });
```

outputs:

```
line 1
line 3
line 2
line 4
```

How can I get the lines in the same order and also know which are from stdout and which are from stderr?

note, [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) says some conflicting things about buffering. On the one hand they say

> By default, pipes for stdin, stdout, and stderr are established between the parent Node.js process and the spawned child. These pipes have limited (and platform-specific) capacity. If the child process writes to stdout in excess of that limit without the output being captured, the child process will block waiting for the pipe buffer to accept more data

But later they mention a setting, `maxBuffer` which says

> maxBuffer  Largest amount of data in bytes allowed on stdout or stderr. If exceeded, the child process is terminated and any output is truncated

Those 2 explanations seem in conflict. I thought maybe setting `maxBuffer` to 0 might be the solution but apparently it's not.

In any case though it's not clear how to unbuffer these streams.

`spawn` itself has [an example in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) but trying it

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const lines = [];
const ch = child_process.spawn(process.argv[0], ['main.js']);

ch.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ch.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ch.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

leads to the same results

```
stdout: log: line1

stderr: error: line2
error: line4

stdout: log: line3

child process exited with code 0
```

I suspect it has to do with making a `Writeable` stream and passing it in with `spawn` but it's not clear how to do that. I tried creating a `Writeable` and passing it in but node complained

```
internal/child_process.js:996
      throw new ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE('stdio', inspect(stdio));
      ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "Writable {
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 0,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: {
      next: null,
      entry: null,
      finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish]
    }
  },
  writable: true,
  _write: [Function: write],
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}" is invalid for option "stdio"
```

Any idea how to make a synchronous or at least correctly interleaved capture of of stdout and stderr when spawning a child process in node?

---

I think what I'm trying to do is apparently impossible. IIUC I need to pass in the same stream for both stdout and stderr to do keep them interleaved correctly and as soon as I do I lose the ability to tell where the output came from.

But, if nothing else I need to results immediately (unbuffered). Imagine I'm making a node based terminal and running commands, that output needs to make it back to me so I can show it (like a text based spinner) where as if it's buffered (which is what I see now) I'll only get the output in chucks.

Comment: I ran on node `10.19.0` and got 1 2 3 4 output. What is your node version?

Comment: I'm on node 12.18.0 for my testing on MacOS

Comment: Do you need to be able to differentiate between stderr and stdout? As has been pointed in the comments below, using a same file as both stderr and stdout allows to get the order as you wish, but this implies writing to a file and it offers no way to know from where the message came. https://repl.it/repls/ScratchyRecklessSpof#index.js

Comment: Yes, you need to know. 'out: file1', 'error: fail', 'out: file2', has a different meaning than 'out: file1', 'out file2', 'error: fail'

Comment: It's all with `echo line 2 >&2` with execFile.

Comment: My comment was asking if you need to differentiate from where each message has been printed. Yours only says that the order matters. Just check the repl.it where you'll understand that the order can be preserved, but you loose the origin of each messages, so if, as in your shell example, there is no way to tell which is an error or not, you won't be able to tell from the ordered log. However if as in your js example the message identify themselves, I guess it's ok: https://repl.it/repls/BeigeUnconsciousDowngrade

Comment: Gentle ping. Could you give some answer to my clarification request? Do you need to be able to differentiate from your code if a message came from the stderr or if it came from the stdout or is it ok as long as they are ordered?

Comment: For my use case I need to know where they came from. I wanted to be able to highlight errors and I can't without knowing which messages are errors. Reading around I find this is apparently [not a solvable problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/can-i-configure-my-shell-to-print-stderr-and-stdout-in-different-colors). It's an issue of how OSes chose to do this from like the 70s and people have just lived with the repercussions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that what you did

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const lines = [];
const ch = child_process.execFile('sh', ['test.sh'], () => {
  console.log(lines.join(''));
});
ch.stdout.on('data', (data) => { lines.push(data); });
ch.stderr.on('data', (data) => { lines.push(data); });
```

is the maximum we can do. The *problem* with your test script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo line 1
echo line 2 >&2
echo line 3
echo line 4 >&2
```

is that the two strings `"line 1\n"` and `"line 3\n"` are written so quickly.

I mean: the data transfer from child to parent is handled by the OS which (probably) uses low level pipes or any other kind of buffer. Even if the child writes unbuffered to `stdout` what happen? The child writes `"line 1\n"`, the OS *buffers* it somewhere and sends a signal to the parent, the signal rises the parent which finally needs to read; if during this time the child writes `"line 3\n"` as well, the OS has no other way than *buffer* it (with the previously written data) so when the parent finally reads the data has no way to know how many (unbuffered) writes were done to write it.

Answer (score 2):

If modifying the actual child process is an option, you could force it to log synchronously by flushing after writing each line.

Example for `main.js`:

```
var logbuffer = require('log-buffer');

const log = msg => {
    console.log(`log: ${msg}`);
    logbuffer.flush();
}
const error = msg => {
    console.error(`error: ${msg}`);
    logbuffer.flush();
}

log('line1');
error('line2');
log('line3');
error('line4');
```

Otherwise, as stated in the Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console) for Console, the console instance is configured to write to `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`. The synchronous/asynchronous [behaviour](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o) of these is described in detail as follows:

[image: screenshot from Node.js documentation]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I don't control the programs I'm spawning. They could be anything, `rust`, `clang`, `make`, `git`, etc... so I can't augment them to flush.  I'm not sure how those docs you linked to help. Is there some way to set stdout and stderr to a virtual file so I can see the output synchronously across platforms?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Since the child process can be arbitrary, I don't think what you've described can be achieved. The quoted documentation was meant to highlight that the Node.js `stdout` and `stderr` are separate and behave synchronously or asynchronously based on the respective platform.

Comment: The docs also said that all platforms are synchronous if a file is passed in hence my wondering if there is a way to pass in a fake/pseudo/virtual file that's unbuffered and that I can read from as the spawned app writes to